# PHP Catchable fatal error : Laravel artisan command not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

I have a project that I haven't been using for a while and started working on it recently when I tried to run any kind of `artisan` command or run `composer update`, `composer install` I get the this error message and failing the command.

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 66 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 101
```

I tried deleting vendor folder and running both `composer update` and `composer install` commands I still ended up with this error. Even deleted the compose.lock file. Also I tried deleting all routes except home route and tried it didn't work either.

Please any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: yes I have that's the only command working without this error but it does nothing

Comment: Are you using the `url()` and `asset()` helper functions within your configuration files?

Comment: @Jackowski I just checked and found that I have used `url()`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the in my service.php. I have been `Socialite` plugin and which required a call back url in the service.php file as `facebook` array with the element of `redirect` to this I have hard-coded the localhost URL in my development but when I host it I have change it to `url('redirect')`.

this is the reason I could not use artisan commans